# Extract data from Email Body

Tags: javascript, windows

So i'm writing a script to automatically collect emails to a Google spreadsheet. I would like from this email to extract some details like the email address, the name, the address, the phone number. So far i managed to extract the date, the subject, the sender details and the body contents. Below i'll attach the email body and also the code i've written so far! If you have contact me directly at this emails.

This a code i've tried so far:

```
    function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  

  ui.createMenu("KingBoss Menu").addItem("Get Emails", "getGmailEmails").addToUi();
  
}

function getGmailEmails() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("warranty");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for(var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
  var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j = 0; j <messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      extractDetails(message);
      GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
    }
      
  }

}

function extractDetails(message) {
  var dateTime = message.getDate();
  var subjectText = message.getSubject();
  var senderDetails = message.getFrom();
  var bodyContents = message.getPlainBody();
  

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.appendRow([dateTime, senderDetails, subjectText, bodyContents]);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.